Title: Handling Skewed Importance Sampling Weights for High-Dimensional Log-Likelihoods
Question:
I am performing importance sampling (IS) for a Bayesian inference problem with the following setup:
1. Data and Model

My data has ( D = 1300 ) dimensions.
The log-likelihood, $ \log p(x \mid \theta) $, is computed from a multivariate normal distribution, resulting in very negative values (e.g., (-3000) or lower).

2. Prior

The prior, $ \log p(\theta)$, is a uniform distribution over ( P = 31 ) parameters.

3. Posterior

I have a posterior proposal distribution, $\pi(\theta)$, which is used to generate ( N = 85,000 ) samples.

4. Importance Sampling

For each sample $ \theta_i $ from the posterior proposal:

Compute the log weights:
$$
\log w_i = \log p(x \mid \theta_i) + \log p(\theta_i) - \log \pi(\theta_i)
$$
Normalize the weights using the log-sum-exp trick:
$$
\hat{w}_i = \frac{\exp(\log w_i)}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} \exp(\log w_j)}
$$
Evaluate the Effective Sample Size (ESS):
$$
\text{ESS} = \frac{(\sum_{j=1}^{N} \hat{w}_j)^{2}}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} \hat{w}_j^2}
$$



5. Issue

The weights are highly skewed, resulting in an ESS close to 1. And a very narrow peaky posterior even with parameters that have a flatter likelihood.
The IS posterior predictive overlaps with the posterior proposal distribution (e.g., within $ 1\sigma $), indicating that the proposal is not severely mismatched.
I need to prune the posterior with importance sampling because my posterior estimate smoothens out several areas of degeneracy that have gaps, leading to very wide posterior predictions.

6. Failed Attempts

I tried shifting the weights using:
$$
  \log w_i^\text{shifted} = \log w_i - \max(\log w)
  $$
but this does not reduce variance. only makes it easier to work with negative values.
Clipping the weights seems unscientific and introduces bias.


Question:
How can I reduce the skewness of the importance sampling weights and improve the effective sample size (ESS) without introducing bias?
Specifically:

Are there systematic techniques to address this issue?
How can I ensure the IS posterior correctly represents the true posterior without excessively narrowing the posterior?

My goal is to use importance sampling to refine my posterior estimates while maintaining a scientifically rigorous approach.

Are you aware of the Pareto smoothing technique of Vehtari et al., 2024 ?

Thanks for the response. I am not. Does it work for such low likelihoods? and thanks! I will check it out.
